# Cant write to directory when not logged in as root

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, amazon-ec2

I am switching a site over to amazon ec2 and the pages that allow a user to upload a file to a directory arent working. When Im logged in as root via ssh I can 'touch' a new file to there but not when Im logged in as my normal user profile. It still says

```
touch: cannot touch `test.txt': Permission denied
```

I've done
chmod 755 -R n

n is the directory, in /var/www/html
Do I have to change something else somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried chmod 777? Might not make a difference, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the ownership of `/var/www/html/n`. If permissions are `755`, only the owner can add files there. Also, if `test.txt` already exists, check who owns it. If the files are owned by `root`, use `chown` to change the owner to your normal account.